# How to display a string/int within a UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift

this is a very simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I am trying to display a high score within a CGRect, but cannot figure out exactly how to do it. I am currently trying to do this on a playground so that might have something to do with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using a UILabelView?

Comment: @NuclearGhost do you mean [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/)?

Comment: Aidan, a `CGRect` is not a view, it is a struct representation of a rectangle.  I strongly recommend you read through [Apple's View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/).

Comment: It doesn't look like you are very familiar with swift... you may want to do some research on UILabels, UIViews, and CGRects. They are 3 different things.

Comment: use `UILabel` to display text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `UILabel` in a Swift playground. Here's how it might look:

[image: Xcode Playground with UILabel Preview]

Here's the code from the playground:

```
import UIKit

let score = 200
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
label.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
label.text = "High Score: \(score)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CGRect` is the frame or dimensions assigned to a `UIView`, not the `UIView` itself. I would suggest creating a `UILabel` and add that to your view. You can set the text on the `UILabel` to, in your case, the high score variable as a string. Im not sure if it is possible to do this in a playground, but I may be mistaken. A XCode project would work perfect for this, but again, im not sure about the playground.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a playground, it would look like this:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground 

let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,500,500))   //create a view and give it a proper size
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,23))  //create a label with a size
label.text = "My Label"                             //give the label some text
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()     //default view in Playground as black background
view.addSubview(label)                              //add the label to the view

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view        //tell playgound to display your view as the root view in the assistant editor
```

You need to open the assistant editor in the playground to see the result (the two circles icon in the upper right corner)